# Traces and exceptions not posted on ApplicationInsights with telemetry client

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

That's the situation.

We have an Azure Function triggered by a Service Bus that should collect messages and post them to ApplicationInsights.

That's the code we wrote for the function

```
public class TopicToApplicationInsightsLogs
{
    private readonly IApplicationInsightsService _appInsightsService;

    public TopicToApplicationInsightsLogs(IApplicationInsightsService appInsightsService)
    {
        _appInsightsService = appInsightsService;
    }

    [FunctionName("TopicToApplicationInsightsLogs")]
    public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("%MonitorLogTopic%", "%MonitorLogSubcription%", Connection = "MonitorLogServiceBusConnectionString")]
        string jsonData,
        ILogger log,
        MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
        string lockToken
    )
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
        var data = jObject.GetValue("Data").ToObject<Common.Domain.Payloads.Entities.MonitorLog>();

        try
        {
            foreach (var edgeLog in data.Data.Logs)
            {
                _appInsightsService.TrackTrace(edgeLog);

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(edgeLog.SerializedException))
                {
                    _appInsightsService.TrackException(edgeLog);
                }

                _appInsightsService.Flush();
            }

            await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(lockToken);
            log.LogInformation($"Posted {data.Data.Logs.Count()} posts.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await messageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync(lockToken);
            log.LogError($"Error posting logs: {ex.Message}", ex);

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the `ApplicationInsightsService.cs` content

```
public class ApplicationInsightsService : IApplicationInsightsService
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public ApplicationInsightsService()
    {
        var appInsightsConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ApplicationInsightsConnectionString", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        var appInsightsInstrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

        var config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
        config.ConnectionString = appInsightsConnectionString;
        //config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer());
        _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(config)
        {
            InstrumentationKey = appInsightsInstrumentationKey
        };
        //_telemetryClient.Context.User.Id = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        //_telemetryClient.Context.Device.Id = Environment.MachineName;
    }

    public void TrackTrace(MonitorLogDataRecord log)
    {
        var traceTelemetry = log.ToTraceTelemetry();
        _telemetryClient.TrackTrace(traceTelemetry);
    }

    public void TrackException(MonitorLogDataRecord log)
    {
        var exception = log.ToExceptionTelemetry();

        _telemetryClient.TrackException(exception);
    }

    public void TrackEvent(MonitorLogDataRecord log)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"log", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(log)}};
        _telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Test", dict);
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        _telemetryClient.Flush();
        // Argh
        //Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
    }
}
```

and the `ApplicationInsightsParser.cs` used to map objects

```
public static class ApplicationInsightsParser
{
    public static TraceTelemetry ToTraceTelemetry(this MonitorLogDataRecord log)
    {
        return new TraceTelemetry
        {
            Timestamp = log.Timestamp,
            //Properties = {{"", ""}},
            Context =
            {
                //Component =
                //{
                //    Version = ""
                //},
                //Device =
                //{
                //    Id = "",
                //    Model = "",
                //    OemName = "",
                //    OperatingSystem = "",
                //    Type = ""
                //},
                //Cloud =
                //{
                //    RoleInstance = "",
                //    RoleName = ""
                //},
                //Flags = 0,
                //InstrumentationKey = "",
                //Location =
                //{
                //    Ip = ""
                //},
                Operation =
                {
                    Name = log.Source
                    //CorrelationVector = "",
                    //Id = "",
                    //ParentId = "",
                    //SyntheticSource = ""
                }
                //Session =
                //{
                //    Id = "",
                //    IsFirst = true
                //},
                //User =
                //{
                //    Id = "",
                //    AccountId = "",
                //    AuthenticatedUserId = "",
                //    UserAgent = ""
                //},
                //GlobalProperties = {{"", ""}}
            },
            //Extension = null,
            //Sequence = "",
            //ProactiveSamplingDecision =SamplingDecision.None,
            Message = log.Content,
            SeverityLevel = log.Level.ParseToSeverity()
        };
    }

    public static ExceptionTelemetry ToExceptionTelemetry(this MonitorLogDataRecord log)
    {
        return new ExceptionTelemetry
        {
            Timestamp = log.Timestamp,
            //Properties = {{"", ""}},
            Context =
            {
                //Component =
                //{
                //    Version = ""
                //},
                //Device =
                //{
                //    Id = "",
                //    Model = "",
                //    OemName = "",
                //    OperatingSystem = "",
                //    Type = ""
                //},
                //Cloud =
                //{
                //    RoleInstance = "",
                //    RoleName = ""
                //},
                //Flags = 0,
                //InstrumentationKey = "",
                //Location =
                //{
                //    Ip = ""
                //},
                Operation =
                {
                    Name = log.Source
                    //CorrelationVector = "",
                    //Id = "",
                    //ParentId = "",
                    //SyntheticSource = ""
                }
                //Session =
                //{
                //    Id = "",
                //    IsFirst = true
                //},
                //User =
                //{
                //    Id = "",
                //    AccountId = "",
                //    AuthenticatedUserId = "",
                //    UserAgent = ""
                //},
                //GlobalProperties =
                //{
                //    {"", ""}

                //}
            },
            //Extension = null,
            //Sequence = "",
            //ProactiveSamplingDecision = SamplingDecision.None,
            //Message = log.Content,
            SeverityLevel = log.Level.ParseToSeverity(),
            //Metrics =
            //{
            //    {"", 0}
            //},
            Exception = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Exception>(log.SerializedException)
            //ProblemId = ""
        };
    }

    private static SeverityLevel ParseToSeverity(this MonitorLogDataRecordLevel logLevel)
    {
        switch (logLevel)
        {
            case MonitorLogDataRecordLevel.Debug:
                return SeverityLevel.Verbose;
            case MonitorLogDataRecordLevel.Info:
                return SeverityLevel.Information;
            case MonitorLogDataRecordLevel.Warn:
                return SeverityLevel.Warning;
            case MonitorLogDataRecordLevel.Error:
                return SeverityLevel.Error;
            case MonitorLogDataRecordLevel.Fatal:
                return SeverityLevel.Critical;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(logLevel), logLevel, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The service is instanced as singleton using `Startup.cs` but even if we get 0 errors when running and we see messages from the queue being processed, searching content on ApplicationInsighs we can't find any trace or exception.

We tried to force `TrackTrace`, `TrackExeption` and `TrackEvent` and after that test we managed to see only `Events`.
[image]
Searching the web leads us to the configuration you can see, but still not working for us.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may have configured `sampling settings` or `LogLevel settings` in the host.json file.

For `sampling settings`, you can refer to [Configure sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#configure-sampling) and [applicationInsights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#applicationinsights).

For `LogLevel`, you can refer to [Configure categories and log levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#configure-categories-and-log-levels).

If that's not the case, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Actually we found the issue, and was related to the function itself, we managed to resolve it by deleting and redeploying a brand new version, without modify nothing! By the way those links you provided may help us to improve the whole flow!